# PDFs don't open

Tags: pdf, evince

PDFs have curiously stopped working for me. I click on them, and nothing happens. PS still works, and opening them in Firefox pdf.js still works too.

When I try to open them with evince through the terminal, it spits out a bunch of repetitive warnings like

```
** (evince:3383): WARNING **: Error setting file metadata: No such file or directory
** (evince:3372): WARNING **: Error when getting information for file '...': No such file or directory
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/50-user.conf", line 9: reading configurations from ~/.fonts.conf is deprecated.
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/50-user.conf", line 9: reading configurations from ~/.fonts.conf is deprecated.
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/50-user.conf", line 9: reading configurations from ~/.fonts.conf is deprecated.
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/50-user.conf", line 9: reading configurations from ~/.fonts.conf is deprecated.
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/50-user.conf", line 9: reading configurations from ~/.fonts.conf is deprecated.
```

For some reason, if I remove all the spaces from the file name, and run the same terminal command, evince will open the file. Clicking on it from nautilus still doesn't work.

Comment: For further information, please see the upstream bug report at https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=771351 .

Answer (score 1):

Discovered why Nautilus refuses to open it—I had installed Adobe Reader 9, and it was listed as the default application—had to go "Open with Other application→Document Viewer"